How to use NODE_POSITION_VIEW to get the centre of a node in the screen view
All I want is to be able to get the UV coordinate of the centre of a mesh (in this case, to take the colour from). However, in the code below, it gets the UV coordinate of the bottom right corner for some reason. I can't figure out what the node value actually is, as the documentation doesn't say, and there's no way to debug the run time values.
shader_type spatial;
render_mode unshaded;

uniform sampler2D screen_texture : hint_screen_texture;
uniform vec2 tiling = vec2(1.0);
uniform vec2 offset = vec2(0.0);

varying vec2 mesh_position;

void vertex() {
    mesh_position = (PROJECTION_MATRIX * vec4(NODE_POSITION_VIEW, 1.0)).xy;
}

void fragment() {
    vec2 centre = mesh_position;
    vec2 local_uv = (SCREEN_UV);
    
    // Adjust for aspect ratio and FOV
    //local_uv.x *= VIEWPORT_SIZE.x / VIEWPORT_SIZE.y;
    //local_uv *= -1.0 / PROJECTION_MATRIX[1][1];
    
    ALBEDO = texture(screen_texture, NODE_POSITION_VIEW.xy).rgb;
}


